# Object edited in view delivered by HttpGet Edit() is not received by HttpPost Edit()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two edit Action methods, one for HttpGet and one for HttpPost. The HttpGet method takes an id parameter, retrieves the appropriate object, and displays it for editing. The HttpPost method takes a parameter that should be the edited object; however, the ids do not match. Why is that mismatch occurring?  I've included the code for my Edit.cshtml view, and for my two Action Methods.

The View:

```
@model WebApplicationPbiBoard.Models.Sprint

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sprint</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.End)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.End)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.End)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

The Action Methods:

```
 //
        // GET: /Sprint/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var sprint = Db.GetById(id);
            return View(sprint);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Sprint/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Sprint editedSprint)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Db.Save(editedSprint);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
                return View(editedSprint);            
        }
```

Here's the GetById method. It's pretty much a wrapper around the NHibernate ISession.GetById method.

```
public T GetById(int id)
        {
            return Session.Get<T>(id);
        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your HttpPost Edit method so you can see what the editedSprint object looks like before saving?

Comment: Yep. The two editable fields (Start and End) are the correct values passed in to the Edit view. The id is 0. I think that what's happening is that a new Sprint is being created (hence the Id = 0), and that sprint is getting the Start and End values. For some reason the Id isn't mapping.

Comment: Whats your Db.GetById() look like?

Comment: Have you manually inspected the Request.Form collection? If so, can you add another parameter corresponding to id and see if it gets populated?

Comment: I updated my question to include the Db.GetById method. @Tejs I'll try what you suggested, but I'm not really sure how. Can you give me any guidance?

Comment: Also, is there anything special about the Id property? For example, does it have a private setter or a setter at all?

Comment: For example, according to the HTML posted, you should be able to type Request.Form["id"] into the watch window on your post action method to inspect the value.

Comment: The signature of the Id property: public virtual int Id {get; private set;}  It's that way to work with NHibernate.

Comment: try making the setter public and see if the result changes i.e. the Id gets the correct value...

Comment: Making the setter public fixed the issue. I'll have to change around my action method. Once I've finished, I'll add the answer as a community wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. Thanks to everyone who helped me with debugging it.

The problem was that, to adhere to NHibernate best practices, the setter for my id property was private. That meant that the controller couldn't set it in the reconstructed model object, so the id was the default value of 0. To solve the problem, I passed the id in as a parameter to the controller and found the right object in my repository, which I then manually updated. Here's the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    //get the right model to edit
    var sprintToEdit = Db.GetById(id);

    //copy the changed fields
    sprintToEdit.Start = start;
    sprintToEdit.End = end;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Db.Save(sprintToEdit);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    else
        return View(sprintToEdit);
}
```